# using the jquery validation plugin, how can I add a regex validation on a textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I am using the jquery validation plugin from: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

How can I add a regex check on a particular textbox?

I want to check to make sure the input is alphanumeric.

Comment: There are lots of additional methods plugins here
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Define a new validation function, and use it in the rules for the field you want to validate:

```
$(function ()
{
    $.validator.addMethod("loginRegex", function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9\-]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Username must contain only letters, numbers, or dashes.");

    $("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {
            "login": {
                required: true,
                loginRegex: true,
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "login": {
                required: "You must enter a login name",
                loginRegex: "Login format not valid"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Note: the addmethod doesn't need to go in document.ready, may as well load it immediately to free up document.ready for stuff that needs to go there.

Comment: What would need to be changed in order to display a specific error message if the value is not alphanumeric and another if it isn't between the min/max length?

Comment: @Cofey - I didn't actually validate (pun intended) that this works, but I updated the example to use custom error messages using the documentation at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options

Answer (score 7):

Not familiar with jQuery validation plugin, but something like this should do the trick:

```
var alNumRegex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/; //only letters and numbers
if(alNumRegex.test($('#myTextbox').val())) {
    alert("value of myTextbox is an alphanumeric string");
}
```

Comment: @karmin79: Thanks for elegant solution. Just minor thing you are missing one ")" before "{".